# Accessing/storing additional attributes using Salesforce Triggered Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

I have setup a Triggered Send inside Sales Cloud (using the MC Connector) and have created a Triggered Send Data Extension which records get appended to when they're triggered.

I would like to know whether it's possible to store additional values in the data extension that I can use within the triggered email? Using the API you can usually pass additional attributes, but how can the same be done when using Salesforce Triggers?

Comment: Would a lookup work? Have an identifier that is passed in SF Trigger used as a pkey in the DE and then do a lookup there to pull in the relational data.

Comment: So the idea isnt that I need it in the email used, I know how to pull that data. Its more for the triggered send DE which keeps a log of the messages sent. Theres a particular field value I need and it changes (which causes the trigger to run).

Comment: Actually I tried the above scenario! But I was able to get my additional fields displayed in email, however these DOES NOT get stored in Triggered send DE :( [LINK] (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287633/activation-failed-trigger-send-in-sales-cloud-using-marketing-cloud-connect?noredirect=1#comment431778_287633) ... I hope the ONLY option is to write manual AMPscript to Insert/Upsert.