# Activation Failed !! Trigger send in Sales cloud using Marketing Cloud Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

This seems strange, where in I had activated the same Triggered send and was working fine... The only change I performed was I **added a Triggered send data extension** in to the definition and added a personalization **First Name** to email; by De-activating and editing. But now I am facing the below error!

I wonder is there any LIMIT or GOVERNOR limit on Number of Triggered def. OR the number times it can be modified?

[image]

## Question 2

Now I am clear on the below that,
1) We can use the personalization fields only if we are using Triggeredsend from Marketing cloud, using SSJS or WS proxy.

2) But if we are using the Triggered send from SalesCloud, then we use personalization fields! - I am NOT confident on this! and this is what I was trying today. Below is , my Test email and DE screenshots.

[image]

[image]

My question here is **why FirstName and LastName does NOT get stored in my DE** and only the SubscriberKey and EMailaddress only gets in?
However you can see I was even able to retrieve these in my email from Contact object:-O 
[image]

Comment: Did the email pass validation in preview, as I described for you in my previous answer?

Comment: Is there a `First Name` column in your Triggered Send DE? If not, than add it and try again

Comment: Thanks @LukasLunow and zuzannamj .... I was able to rectify this... Yes the issue was with the PERSONALIZATION field... I am EDITING my question so I am clear on what I wanted to ask here.